# Testflight app doesn't show my personal colours

Tags: swiftui, colors, assets, testflight

I'm trying to upload an app to the App Store. When I try to install it on my device through Xcode, the app is displayed correctly as it was created. However, when it's installed via TestFlight, the colors I've set for various UI elements (buttons, background, etc.) are not displayed correctly. It seems that my TestFlight app doesn't have access to my asset files where I created all the colors, but it's only using system-defined colors (for example, Color.white and Color.black work perfectly, while Color("Green") does not).

Any tip to fix it?
Thanks!

I tried to change colours and rebuilding but nothing changed